# How do I upload my Bootstrap developed template to my web hosting provider server

Tags: web-hosting, bootstrap

I have just developed a bootstrap template offline and I want to know how I can upload these files to a live site without using a CMS application. Do I just upload them via FTP to the hosting server or are there other alternatives to deploying these files?

Comment: This is really too broad a question since there's numerous ways to transfer/upload files to a hosting account. In addition to the methods Abu lists below, many control panels like cPanel and Plesk have built-in file managers that will upload and set permissions on files simultaneously. If you have a hosting account with a control panel, look for that option.

Answer (score 2):

FTP is a good way to upload files to a live server especially if they are static files. Even if they are php files ftp/sftp is the easy way.

There are other methods for e.g. [git sync](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6373538/2713831) etc. But I'll assume you're just uploading regular html/php files, in which case ftp is good enough and widely used.

[Filezilla](https://filezilla-project.org/) is a good free ftp program to upload files to the server.

Once you have that make the connection to your server using your ftp/sftp credentials. I would recommend using sftp as that is secure.

Once you're connected locate your `public_html` folder and just transfer all your files there overwriting any index.html files. Be sure to name your homepage index.html or index.php as most servers are configured to run that as the index file.

If your index file is inside a directory, place it outside of that and into your public_html to avoid `http://example.com/dir/index.html`

Hope that helps.